# Trouble with Style by attribute in OpenLayers vector layer features

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to use a `${iconURL}` style property to determine what icon will be displayed on a vector layer feature. The icon is not displayed.

My layer initialization code is:

```
var s = {
    externalGraphic: "imgs/pp/${iconURL}",
    graphicWidth: 20,
    graphicHeight: 20,
    pointRadius: 20,
    fillOpacity: .2,
};
this.vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vectorLayer",{style: s});
```

My feature add code is:

```
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( lon ,lat ).transform(
this.fromProjection,
this.toProjection 
);

marker1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)
    .transform( this.fromProjection, this.toProjection), 
    {"myFid":featureID, "iconURL": "stop.png"});
this.vectorLayer.addFeatures([marker1]);
```

The icon does not display.

If I put an actual filename in var s instead of ${iconURL} the icon is displayed.
I have carefully checked the value of ${iconURL} etc. It all look fine. I seems that the variable replacement is not being done or something.

I just can't work it out. Please help a poor tortured soul.

regards
Grant

Comment: I have made some progress - but not yet working.I discovered that when creating the layer I should not be passing a StyleMap but rather just a string representing the object. ie. not: 

    this.vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vectorLayer",{StyleMap: s});

but rather 

    this.vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("vectorLayer",{style: {externalGraphic: "iconURL"});

Also I should not have been using StyleMap keyword but rather style.
I have updated the code above. Overall it is still not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems directly setting a layer's style as well, but it works if you use a StyleMap instead. So, you were on the right track in the first place except you needed to specify that your style was for the StyleMap's default rendering intent:

```
var s = {
    externalGraphic: '${iconURL}',
    graphicHeight: 20  
};      
var myStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    "default": s
});
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer",{
    styleMap: myStyleMap
});
```

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/m394H/) on JSFiddle, and a brief mention in the [OpenLayers docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/StyleMap-js.html#OpenLayers.StyleMap).